# Excel: Return Matching component from a multi-string search

Tags: excel, excel-formula

What I am asking for in my question is in column E

[image: What I am asking for in my question is in column E]

I am conducting a search within the following example cell (`A1`) that contains:

```
Pluvhcuwvc wgd 2 1:22 Bal wgwvwvv
```

using the following formula:

```
=sum(--isnumber(search(x1:x13, A1)))>0)
```

The list of cells `x1:x13` is `Bal` followed by `Jan21` to `Dec21` months all in `MMMYY` format.

As opposed to returning `TRUE`, I would like the cell to return the text that matched and apply the formula to column A.

Been experimenting but failed to retrieve much better than just the contents of adjacent A column.

The strings in column A do not have a consistent format either.

Let me know if you need any extra details to help and please let me know if the format needs some work.

Comment: It didn't - was the {B2:B4} meant to refer to the cells below where I am working?

Comment: Do you have an actual piece of sample data in the form of a screenshot including your expected result?

Comment: added - I can get from E to B, just trying to get to E

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following array formula:

```
=INDEX(I:I,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH($I$1:$I$13,A2)),0))
```

Array formula after editing is confirmed by pressing `ctrl` + `shift` + `enter`

[image]

Comment: Amazing! Thanks. Was experimenting with the index matching but gave up... Appreciate the help.